How can i fetch given day of any given year?
I'm working on a local program in which I want the first day of the given number of year like(Monday, Tuesday etc). How can I have it?
firstly I try datetime module for this purpose but it gives current date. But i don't want current date or day. I want day of given year.

If you knew what day of the week January 1 of your year of interest was, would that be enough to determine what you want (which I don't really understand)?  Datetime module can do that easily.

Create a datetime.date object for the desired date, then use its .weekday() method.  What is the difficulty?

(1) What language is this "Local Program" being written in? (2) It sounds like you are looking for the day of the week for the Jan 1st of each year, is that the case? Date functions/methods for almost every application type have a method by which you can feed in the full date rather than "now". Differs for each language and is usually provided in basic examples. After creating the date variable it is almost always possible to perform modifications (like: changing the year ...) and then using a formatting feature to provide the Day of Week value for the variable.

To get the first day of the year, set month to 1 and day to 1, then use %A to format the date with only the weekday
from datetime import date

year = 1997
d = date(year, 1, 1)
print(d.strftime("%A"))

